# It's is possoble create objects from a Class passed as parameter?

Tags: java, class

I done a method that receive a class and a int. I want to know if is possible and how I do to create an object from the passed Class parameters.

```
public void createObject(Class clazz, int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        //new object from the clazz
    }
}
```

It's possible to do this? I will create te objects to run in threads.

How can I assure that the Class implements Callable?

EDIT: it's possible calling a Construcor with arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you means like this?

```
if(Callable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    Callable obj = (Callable) clazz.newInstance();

} else if (MyAbstractClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    MyAbstractClass obj = (MyAbstractClass) clazz.newInstance();

} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(clazz+" not valid");
}
```

If you have a constructor which takes arguments you can do

```
Callable obj = (Callable) clazz.getConstructor(int.class).newInstance(10);
```

Comment: Hmmmm...yes yes. I did know it. It's possible to assute that the class received as parameter implements Callable or extends one of my abstract class?

Comment: Only constructor with no arguments can be used? And if I want to call one with a argument, can I use the Class yet?

Comment: I have added an example. You have to know the type of parameters and what arguments you want to pass.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780868/its-is-possoble-create-objects-from-a-class-passed-as-parameter/6780909#6780909) answered the first question very well.
2. public void createObject(Class<? extends Callable> clazz, int n){

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (!Callable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        // whatever error condition
    }
    Callable callable = (Callable) clazz.newInstance();
```

Comment: This is good, but would not my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780868/its-is-possoble-create-objects-from-a-class-passed-as-parameter/6780988#6780988 compile time guarantee that the clazz is a Callable and eliminate the need for casting.  I do not have a compiler handy - so I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

This [method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) will help you check whether the passed class implements an interface/extends a class.

Comment: emory's suggestion of using generic method is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more on this here ... http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html